# Contentview within horizontal listview not expanded

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I create dynamically horizon listview by listview rotation 270 degrees and contentview in datatemplate rotation 90 degrees but contentview doesn't expanded

I have tried to set VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" and  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" and also tried to set RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint and RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint but it's doesn't work

[image: that's i got]

```
<RelativeLayout HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="Pink" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView Rotation="270" x:Name="Horizonlist" ItemsSource="Hlist" RowHeight="130" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="#EEEEEE" BackgroundColor="Gray"
                                          RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=-15}"
                                          RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=-0.5, Constant=15}"
                                          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=40}"
                                          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" 
                                          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ContentView Rotation="90" BackgroundColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
                                    <StackLayout  Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Green" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200">
                                            <Label Rotation="0" Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ContentView>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
           </RelativeLayout>
```

Expected layout
[image: Expected layout]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot about the effect that you want?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I added already, thanks

Comment: @SutineeM. I would advise using Grid instead of "StackLayout inside a ContentView" inside the datatemplate since the Grid layout scales out pretty well. Adding contentview and stacklayout is too much complexity i would say. Also try not to use hardcoded height and width for the Label rather restrict them with line breaks. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dilmah I try to using Grid but it's doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding carousel_list}" IsVisible="{Binding carousel_visibility}">
                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <Image Source="{Binding image}" VerticalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="300"/>
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ScrollView>
```

**in oreder to achieve horzontal listview like output you can use the bindable layout as per shown in the above code**

Comment: Why scrollview doesn't scroll?

Comment: Scrollview doesn't scroll because i set srollview within relativelayout so i just removed relativelayout and It's work now. Thank you